# Append text only one to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

So, I have the ms_trans DataGridView...

I'm trying to solve saving problem by this:

- The for loop doesn't give back the last value

So, when I click save, the button insert a "" string to all cells, but every time I click this will added.

```
int Last = ms_trans.Rows.Count;    
if (ms_trans.Rows[Last - 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "<append>")
```

This If statement has NullReferenceException. Why?

First, I added with Last-1, it worked (Only the Last gave OutOfRangeExeption). Why isn't working is this with getting the value?

Comment: Have you checked if `Last` is ALWAYS `> 0`?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.